# java search in String

Tags: java, string

Sorry for a really lame question, just figured out that I'm not familiar with String operations o_0 What I have is a string

```
http://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#access_token= 533bacf01e11f55b536a565b57531ad114461ae8736d6506a3&expires_in=86400&user_id=8492
```

what I need are 3 strings:

```
 access token="533bacf01e11f55b536a565b57531ad114461ae8736d6506a3"
 expiration="86400"
  user_id="8492"
```

How can I divide the given String into 3 strings I need? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps :

`String str = "http://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#access_toke..."`

`str = str.substring(str.indexOf("#") + 1);`

`str.split("&");`

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet, using regular expressions:

```
String url = "http://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#access_token=533bacf01e11f55b536a565b57531ad114461ae8736d6506a3&expires_in=86400&user_id=8492";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".+access_token=(.+)&expires_in=(.+)&user_id=(.+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);

if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println("access_token=" + matcher.group(0));
    System.out.println("expires_in=" + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("user_id=" + matcher.group(2));
}
```

The three matches end up in (respectively) group 0, 1 and 2 of the matcher object.